# Divs Overlapping after changing text inside top div from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code I have a div that is empty when the user first navigates to the page. If the user clicks on a button, a javascript function is called and the div is filled with the information calculated in javascript. For some reason, the top div overlaps the bottom div when the text gets added to it. The only way I have been able to fix the issue is to add an empty button above the bottom div.

Here is my html:

```
<div>
    <div style="text-align:left">

    </div>
    <div id="myDIV" style="height:400px; display:none">
    </div>
</div>
<!--<div id="chartdiv" style="position:relative; float:left"></div>-->

<div style="display:block">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("DetailsLoadRecordDummy", Model.LoadRecordDummies);}
</div>
```

The above code has overlap, but it does not if I change it to something like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="text-align:left">
       <button><button>
    </div>
    <div id="myDIV" style="height:400px; display:none">
    </div>
</div>
<!--<div id="chartdiv" style="position:relative; float:left"></div>-->

<div style="display:block">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("DetailsLoadRecordDummy", Model.LoadRecordDummies);}
</div>
```

I have tried changing the position of the bottom div to relative but that has not worked. For some reason that makes the button above the divs (I did not include its code) not clickable.

Also, the javascript onclick function that is called changes the div w/ id="myDiv" to display:block, if that is useful information. Right now the function adds a chart into the div.

Screenshot of page before user clicks view file, div above Load Record Information table is empty
[image]

Screenshot of page after user clicks view file, rather than moving the Load Record Information table down, the chart overlaps
[image]

Comment: Can you please illustrate what is overlapping, and also what styles are applied to the divs, screen shot would be most useful.

Comment: I added 2 screenshots to my post for better understanding of my issue.

Comment: @Cami Without viewing the source, it's hard to determine the solution. Possible causes: chart height greater than 400px (declared in inline style); absolute positioning; negative margins.

Comment: @Cami I think you should make a code pen or similar of the html js css and the issue presenting itself so we can inspect it and help out that way. It is not a complete picture you've painted here - need the styles (in a code pen/ jsfiddle)